# Question on interpreting a logistic regression with information from the confusion matrix

Tags: probability, bayesian, logistic, generalized-linear-model

So I have a logistic regression and the I have the following information as outputs:

- The probability of the y variable being either one or zero
- a normalized confusion matrix as follows:

| T zero | False One = B |
| --- | --- |
| False Zero | T One = A |

So if Probability of 1 for a given set of inputs is X, the probability a true 1 is A and probability of a false 1 is B, then the true probability of 1 in this instance is:

$P(1) =X* \frac{(A)}{(A+B)}$

Am I correct in my understanding?

*edit: to clarify what I mean by normalize is that each number is converted to a percentage. See example at https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Normalized-Confusion-Matrix-A-row-represents-an-instance-of-the-actual-class-ie-an_fig1_308074430

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. Can you add some more details or make it clearer? I'm a bit lost on the 'normalized confusion matrix' line.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: I have made edits to respond to both points